# TCPDF hello world example using composer

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

What is the minimum "hello world" example for TCPDF?

I see over 60 examples at https://tcpdf.org/examples/ and none of them work with composer and they are all very complicated.

I'm looking for something simple so I can start learning off of that.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The title of the post specifies that they want to use TCPDF with Composer and I found that the accepted answer does not utilize Composer to do this.

First, include TCPDF in Composer. Add the following code to your composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.2.13"
}
```

If there is an existing composer.lock file in the directory, then run from the command-line:

```
composer install
```

Otherwise, run from the command-line:

```
composer update
```

Create a PHP file with the following code:

```
<?php
// Load autoloader (using Composer)
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$pdf = new TCPDF();                 // create TCPDF object with default constructor args
$pdf->AddPage();                    // pretty self-explanatory
$pdf->Write(1, 'Hello world');      // 1 is line height

$pdf->Output('hello_world.pdf');    // send the file inline to the browser (default).

?>
```

Open this page from your web browser and you should see an example PDF document saying Hello World.

Comment: In case of this error : 
*TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file*
modify that part of code :

       ``` ob_end_clean();
        $pdf->Output('hello_world1.pdf');
       ```

Comment: it says "Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`."